# Git Rebase for feature X on feature Z after merge on staging

Tags: git, rebase

How to Rebase right for the following problem, is rebase the right Solution?
We use rebase for default branching strategies and the only merge happens in MR normaly.

```
 A--B--C (staging)
        \
         D--E--F (x-feature)
                \
                 G--H--I (y-feature)
```

I've a staging branch, where I've created a x-feature branch and then I've created my MR for this branch but I need the implemented features and so I've created an other y-feature from my x-feature branch.

And When I am right, when the MR is merged it should look like the following and my y-feature Hangs around, because the MR-Branch gets deleted after MR.

```
 A--B--C--D--E--F (staging)
          
               \
                G--H--I (y-feature)
```

How do I get my y-feature reattached to my staging branch, without data loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described, everything will work just fine.  **Branches are just pointers to commits** (they don't point to other branches), so when the `x-feature` branch is merged into the `staging` branch, the `y-feature` branch will still point to commit `I`, and `G`'s parent commit will still be commit `F`. At that moment both `staging` and `x-feature` will be pointing to commit `F`, and if the `x-feature` branch is deleted it doesn't matter.

**Side Note**: if branch `x-feature` is re-written for some reason before it is merged into `staging`, then commit `F` may no longer exist on the `staging` branch. In that case you probably would want to rebase `y-feature` onto the new `staging` branch, with a command similar to this:

```
git rebase --onto origin/staging F
```

That would replay commits G, H, and I on top of the updated `staging` branch.